# Facing an error on register and login javascript api with mysql2 database

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, reactjs, post

I'm trying to send a post using the Postman application. My request from the body is:

```
{

    "username" : "UserAbc",
    "password" : "password"
}
```

the registered post is correct, and it gives me the token.

```
{
    "token": "42dfe660-235a-11ea-8453-47319dfb7448"
}
```

When I try to post the login with the same user and password,
it always gives me: "error": "Password wrong!" + the error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

```
app.post('/register', async(req, res) => {

  const username = (req.body || {}).username;
  const password = (req.body || {}).password;


  if (!username || !password) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Missing required parameters'
    });
    return;
  }
  await sequelize.sync({force : true})
  let user = new User({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  });
await   user.save();

  let tokenKey = uuidv1();
  let newToken = new Token({
    token: tokenKey,
    expire: ~~(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600 * 24,
  });
  newToken.save();

  res.status(200).send({ token: tokenKey });
});

app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
  const username = (req.body || {}).username;
  const password = (req.body || {}).password;

  if (!username || !password) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Missing required parameters'
    });
    return;
  }
  await sequelize.sync({force : true})
  let user = User.findOne( { where: {username: username} } );
  if (user == null) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: "User not exist" });
  }
  if (user.password !== password) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: "Password wrong!" });
  }

  let tokenKey = uuidv1();
  let newToken = new Token({
    token: tokenKey,
    expire: ~~(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600 * 24,
  });
  await newToken.save();

  res.status(200).send({ token: tokenKey });
});
```

Also this is my mysql database:

```
mysql.createConnection({
  host: host,
    user : user,
    password : pswd
}).then(async (connection) => {
    await connection.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' + dbname);
    await connection.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + dbname);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.warn(err.stack);
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbname, user, pswd,{
    dialect : 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    },
});



let User = sequelize.define('user', {
    username : {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
    },
    password : Sequelize.STRING
});

let Token = sequelize.define('token', {
    token : {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
    },
    expire : Sequelize.INTEGER //timestamp
});

User.hasMany(Token);
```

Comment: Hi! maybe problem in ```await sequelize.sync({force : true})``` each POST request
```sequelize.sync({force : true})``` each call recreated table with empty user.

Try delete ```sequelize.sync({force : true})```  in ```/login``` route


    And use ```res.status(401).end({message if error})``` instead of ```res.status(401).send```